# Open subset condition is necessary or just sufficient for the differentiation under integral sign theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expectation

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\Omega$ be a measure space. Suppose that the function $f:X\times\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ satisfies the following theorem conditions:

1. $f(x,\omega)$ is a measurable function of $\omega$ for each $x\in X$.
2. For almost all $\omega \in \Omega$, the derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,\omega)}{\partial x_{i}}$ exists for all $x \in X.$
3. There is an integral function $\Theta:\Omega\longleftrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\frac{\partial f(x,\omega)}{\partial x_{i}}|\leq \Theta$ for all $x \in X.$
   Then 
   $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}}\int_{\Omega}^{}f(x,\omega)dP(\omega)=\int_{\Omega}^{}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}f(x,\omega)dP(\omega).$$

I have got a problem where other conditions satisfy except the openness. Can I invoke the theorem where $X$ is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

If I choose my $X=\{(x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^n| \ x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n}=1\}$, and $f(x,\omega)=\bigg[max\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}(t-r_{i}),0\bigg)\bigg]^\alpha$ where $\alpha \geq 1$, $t$ be a constant and $r_{i}'s$ are random variables, Will the theorem work now.

Comment: This will remain true on the interior of $X$, but you can't say what happens on the boundary, for the usual reasons about the derivative not being defined.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If i choose the $X$ defined as above Will it work? Actually derivatives are exist in an open set containing the $X$. If I want to work with one sided derivative will there be any problem ?

Comment: That's a subspace, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, so it's rather different (it has empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for one thing). If you parametrise it to make it explicitly $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (e.g. by putting $x_n=1-x_1-x_2-\dotsb$), then you can differentiate just as if you are in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: How do you say this is a subspace? Because $0$ does not  belongs to $X$.

Comment: It's an affine subspace (the difference of two of its elements lies in a subspace). It's still diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, which is the important part.

Comment: Actually I don't have much knowledge about these terminology. So finally I want to just know: Can I use the theorem with  $X$ and $f(x,\omega)$ defined as above ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.